# Private Endpoint - Azure

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-virtual-network, azure-private-link

If I have a databricks cluster in azure and want to use Event Hubs in a Private Endpoint do I just point the DB Cluster to the Private Alias?

Is there any challenge with Databricks being already configured with network routes etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use the private endpoint to make the Databricks and the Event Hubs communicate with each other, then you need to create the Databricks in the VNet and create a private endpoint for the Event Hub in that VNet. Get more details in [Deploy Azure Databricks in your Azure virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/vnet-inject). It shows the feature:

> Connect Azure Databricks to other Azure services (such as Azure
> Storage) in a more secure manner using service endpoints.

The VNet should be in the same region and subscription with the Databricks, you can control the security with the NSG rules.